# Cannot see the kernel Python 3 (TensorFlow 2.3 Python 3.7 GPU Optimized) in sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

Amazon sagemaker [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-kernels.html)
states that **TensorFlow 2.3 Python 3.7 GPU Optimized** kernel should be available to use when a sagemaker notebook instance is used. But when I use a *ml.p2.xlarge* (us-west-2) [amazon sagemaker notebook instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi.html) I cannot see the *TensorFlow 2.3 Python 3.7 GPU Optimized* kernel

I can see other kernles such as

- Python 3 (TensorFlow 2.1 Python 3.6 GPU Optimized)
- Python 3 (MXNet 1.8 Python 3.7 GPU Optimized)

Do I need to enable some particular setting to see *TensorFlow 2.3 Python 3.7 GPU Optimized* kernel

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-kernels.html) you linked to says that the kernels are available in Sagemaker Studio. I suppose the Sagemaker notebook instances do no have the entire list of kernels that Studio has.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30199593)